# How can I customize the cpu in visual stadio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I need to test my program on a specific environment. I want to know how I can customize the cpu or ram usage, or see what will happen when I run my program to the hardware. I need this information:

- memory usage
- cpu usage

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I think using a virtual machine (ex. Virtual Box) for testing should be better.